# Moodle and SCORM .zip packages

Tags: macos, moodle, scorm

I have a scorm package that works in Moodle.  However, if unzip it to a folder and then rezip it and try to use it I get the following in Moodle:
"Incorrect file package - missing imsmanifest.xml or AICC structure"

Note, I'm doing this because I was trying to debug it and drilled down to this simple test:

1. Start with working scorm .zip package "TestCourse.zip"
2. On mac os x, I double click to extract it to the current folder.
3. I cmd click on it and selected decompress which makes "TestCourse2.zip"
4. I try to use "TestCourse2.zip" on Moodle as a scorm package and get the error above.

I tried using a different program to re-zip the folder and got the same results.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you rezip the folder itself. You shouldn't do this. You should go into the folder root and then rezip all the contents to generate a new valid package.

Comment: Applying palm to face :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

imsmanifest.xml must be in the root of the zip file, not inside any folder (and do not change structure in any other way because the imsmanifest have dependencies with the other files).